# Sending reviewers a free version of paid iOS apps

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I would like to be able to send a few blogs and review websites a free version of my iOS app. The app costs 1$. Is there a way I can send them a free invite to the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can provide 100 promo codes for each version of your app. More detail can be found in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html).